# geth version does not change after upgraded (apt-get)

Tags: go-ethereum

I want to upgrade my geth node from 1.6.7 to 1.7.2. However it did not work. How can I solve it?

```
$ sudo apt-get install ethereum
Unpacking ethereum (1.7.2+build11187+xenial) over (1.6.7+build10273+xenial) ...
Setting up ethereum (1.7.2+build11187+xenial) ...

$ geth version
Geth
Version: 1.6.7-stable
$ which geth
/usr/bin/geth <-- geth is not changed
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get upgrade` ?

Comment: Also make sure you using the latest version of go, this might affect the download.

Comment: Can you check if there's an instance running? `ps -ef | grep -i geth`. Worst case you can restart the machine.

Comment: @jojeyh I'm sorry for the late reply. Yes you are completely right. I just did 'sudo apt-get upgrade' then it worked. If you post it as the answer, I'll accept it. Thank you so much.

Comment: How about the degrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type in `sudo apt-get upgrade` to upgrade to the newest version of geth and you should be good to go!